# Group by unique values from Active Directory groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

Inside of an Active Directory structure, there are values set in these fields within a group

- extensionAttribute1
- extensionAttribute2
- extensionAttribute3
- extensionAttribute4

There are about 300 groups with one or more these values set and I'm looking for an efficient way to get these grouped by extensionAttribute2 in a hash table.

The format I'm hoping to retrieve is below. I spaced it out for it to be more readable, but essentially a hashtable with each unique value of extensionAttribute2 being set to a value that is an array of group objects that have that value in extensionAttribute2.

```
@{
  "001"=@(
          Group-Object-1454,
          Group-Object-221,
          Group-Object-33,
          ...
        )
  "002"=@(
          Group178,
          Group2243,
          Group3774,
          ...
        )
  ...
}
```

My attempts have ended less than savory. I realize I could make a large foreach look and construct it that way, but I'm hoping this can be done more efficiently.

I thought this would work but it fails with `Select-Object: null parameter`

```
Get-ADGroup -LdapFilter $Filter -Properties extensionAttribute2 | Select-Object extensionAttribute2, $_ | Group-Object {$_.extensionAttribute2}
```

Another attempt I've made, which was more fruitful, but not quite there just returned unique extensionAttribute2 values

```
Get-ADGroup -LdapFilter $Filter -Properties extensionAttribute2 | select-object extensionAttribute2 | Group {$_}
```

This returned something in the right direction, but I'm stumped beyond this.

```
@{
  @{extensionAttribute2="001"},
  @{extensionAttribute2="002"},
  @{extensionAttribute2="003"},
  ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ht = @{}

Get-ADGroup -LdapFilter $Filter -Properties extensionAttribute2 |
 foreach { $ht[$_.extensionattribute2] += @($_.name) }

$ht
```